# Noun for "playing of the video/audio" object

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word which means *running of this media event*?

For example:

> The advertisement was played 428 times over the promotions period.
>
> The advertisement had four-hundred and twenty-eight *word-goes-here*
>   over the period.

The word needs to encompass both video and audio media.

---

The specific problem I have to solve is what to put on a report:

```
Media File:                    Buy_Duff_Beer.wmv
From:                          Monday, 1 August 2011
To:                            Wednesday 31 August 2011
Total Playings:                4,523
Average Playings Per Hour:     32
```

*Playings* is the best word I've come up with, and I really don't like  it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The noun form of 'to play' is *play*. So you could say:

> Average plays per hour
>
> Total plays

You can play a song (or another piece of audio media), or a movie/video. iTunes also refers to a *play count* for how many times you have listened to a song, or watch a video. So you would say:

> In iTunes, my favorite song has a play count of 4,000.

I would recommend *plays* over *play count*, however.

Comment: “Plays” is absolutely the right term.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using *runs* as a noun here.

Answer (score 0):

What about "broadcast"?

> "The advertisement had four-hundred and twenty-eight broadcasts over
>   the period. Some audio, some video."

Comment: That would work, except in my situation. I need to count each media file running on each device, while a "broadcast" would imply an unknown number of receiving devices.

Answer (score 0):

To emphasize the advertiser, you could try one of:

- transmissions
- presentations
- deliveries

To emphasize the consumer, perhaps:

- receptions
- reviews
- views